# Excluding that SCSS sheet when I build React app in webpack hosted in external app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am running into an issue with my hosted React app within some external application. There is a CSS sheet that lives in the host app, which is impacting my application's styles/format. I want to exclude that CSS sheet when I build my app. I have tried the below code within my webpack rule, but that did not help:

```
{
  test: /\.s?scss$/,
  exclude: /amzn\/vendor-central-trim\/src\/aui\/aui-shim\.scss/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader',
     'sass-loader',
  ],
},
```

Here is what the directories looks like in dev-tool source page:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like this css file is included in the host applications `header` in the HTML? Nothing you do in your build can exclude this, as its outside the remit of your build system. The only way to totally isolate would be for the host page to load your stuff in an iframe, but that can bring its own problems. It could be practical for you though, and should be considered.

Comment: I just remembered also you can use Shadow DOM to workaround this. See https://gourav.io/blog/render-react. This will ensure your app has CSS isolated from the parent page, without using a cumbersome iframe. "If you render React element(s) inside a shadow DOM, the React element(s) won’t inherit any styles from the page CSS. For example, a third-party plugin that overlays some UI on top of a page would use a shadow DOM to prevent its UI from being affected by any page style."

Comment: Libraries exist to help you do this:  https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow (popular), https://github.com/apearce/react-shadow-root or https://github.com/DePayFi/react-shadow-dom, others probably exist